# How are audio files loaded in webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, web-crawler

I'm examining [this](http://parand.se/?p=5026) webpage. I could discover that the audio files are not loaded at the beginning. And the following tag is appended to the html when I click on a play button.

```
<div id="mp3_jplayer_items" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; width:0px; height:0px;">
    <div id="mp3_jplayer_1_8" style="left: -999em; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
        <img id="jp_poster_0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;">
        <audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="none" src="http://www.parand.se/audio/kodak/minoo-javan-04-pache-laili.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I click on another audio the `src` attribute changes to the link to the new audio.
When I load the page with network tab of the inspector open I get so many requests first and then it stops. Then when I click on an audio file I get this request:

```
curl 'http://www.parand.se/audio/kodak/minoo-javan-14-khorouskhan.mp3' -H 'Host: www.parand.se' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0' -H 'Accept: audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Referer: http://parand.se/?p=5026' -H 'Range: bytes=0-' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
```

Which is the request for downloading the file. Not getting the link to the file.

On the other hand when I download the webpage with firefox I don't find any link to any mp3 file in it either any occurance of the work `khorouskhan` which is inside the link and is in the name of the song.

```
# fox is the directory in which I've downloaded the webpage.

$ grep -RPo 'khorouskhan' fox | sort | uniq
# this has no output at all.
$ grep -RPo '[^"]*\.mp3' fox | sort | uniq 
fox/files/jquery_002.js:),this.element.empty(),delete this.instances[this.internal.instance]},enable:function(){},disable:function(){},_testCanPlayType:function(t){try{return t.canPlayType(this.format.mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:     data = { is_download: p.download , url: p.list[track].mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:     exData.mp3 = p.list[track].mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:     that.dl_runinfo( p.list[p.tr].mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:         media[ track.formats[0] ] = track.mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:         media['mp3'] = this.plugin_path + '/mp3/silence.mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:         var pU = ( preL !== false ) ? preL[ this.pl_info[this.tID].tr ].mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:                     arr[j].mp3 = this.f_undo.f_con( arr[j].mp3
fox/files/mp3-jplayer-2.js:' + p.list[track].mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:div.player-track-title.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:iframe.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:span.mp3-finding, span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:ul.ul-mjp.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:        div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:            div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:            .dark div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:        .dark div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:        .text div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .bigger1 span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .bigger2 span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .bigger3 span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .bigger4 span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .bigger5 span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .dark .mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .dark div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .dark.outline div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .nopopoutbutton div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .noscreen div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .outline div.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .statusMI span.mp3-finding, .statusMI span.mp3-tint, div.statusMI span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .statusMI span.mp3-tint, .statusMI span.mp3
fox/files/v1-silver.css:    .text div.mp3
fox/index.html:.mp3
fox/index.html:.a-mjp.mp3
fox/index.html:.transport-MI div, .mp3
```

**My question is:**

I think that JavaScript should get the link either from an API call to the server, or the links should be hard-coded. I think the grep result shows that **1.1** it's either It is not hard-coded, or that **1.2** the webpage I download from the browser is not really all of what the server has given to my browser. On the other hand I don't see any other request else that the download request in my network tab. And I believe that means it's either **2.1** Not gotten from an API call, or **2.2** The network tab does not show all the requests that are sent from my browser.

So basically. What I think is:

```
(1.1 or 2.1) = true
(!1.1 or 1.2) = true
(!2.1 or 2.2) = true
```

So Which of {1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2} are true here? Or what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but I might aswell provide the answer incase anyone is wondering.

There is a request, after all the scripts have been loaded, for a playlist with id=42768, this request goes [here](https://parand.se/?audioigniter_playlist_id=42768). This request contains all the links and info about the tracks in the playlist (such as track name, title, media link

It seams to be a simple JSON API and the website is built on the audioignitor music player plugin for wordpress. As for how it gets the playlist id, this seams to be some server-side rendering (I assume it is done by the plugin). The url for the api is passed in the tags of the div with class `audioigniter-root`.